# Natural join opertaion returns only the first table in mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, natural-join

i have 2 tables in my database , one is called personalfirstteaminfo and the second one is status-kids

the common column between the two tables is player_id

i would like to make a query that joins the two tables , and also creats an age column for each row.

now i have used this query which works - but i get only the data in the personalfirstteam table. i do not see the status-kids columns (which are status and kids)

> SELECT `p`.* ,TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,birthday,CURDATE()) as age FROM `personalfirstteaminfo` as `p` natural join (select `s`.* from `status-kids` as `s`) as T

any ideas?
when i try to do it like this

> SELECT `p`.*,`s`.* FROM `personalfirstteaminfo` as `p`,`status-kids` as `s` where `p`.player_id = `s`.player_id
>
> it does return the values i need , but the player_id column is shown twice.

thank you.

Comment: Don't select *, select just the fields you need.

Comment: `mysql` is not `sql-server`. Which one is it? Also, why do you fall back to the pre-1992 style of joining in your second query?

Answer (score 0):

You didnt select any columns from the second table - try:

```
SELECT p.*, t.* ,TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,birthday,CURDATE()) as age 
FROM personalfirstteaminfo as p natural join (select s.* from status-kids as s) as T
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
SELECT *, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,birthday,CURDATE()) as age 
FROM personalfirstteaminfo as p 
natural join `status-kids`
```

Please note:

- use simple * without naming any table
- omit the unneeded subselect
- the table name `status-kids` got to be escaped because it contains a dash.

For a natural join MySQL will do the following

> - The redundant column is eliminated and the column order is correct according to standard SQL:
> - First, coalesced common columns of the two joined tables, in the order in which they occur in the first table
> - Second, columns unique to the first table, in order in which they occur in that table
> - Third, columns unique to the second table, in order in which they occur in that table
> - The single result column that replaces two common columns is defined using the coalesce operation. - That is, for two t1.a and t2.a the
>     resulting single join column a is defined as a = COALESCE(t1.a, t2.a),
>     where: COALESCE(x, y) = (CASE WHEN V1 IS NOT NULL THEN V1 ELSE V2 END)

Source: [MySQL manual, Join Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/join.html)